# Application cannot be run in WIN32 mode in windows 2000

Tags: computer-forensics

I'm using windows 2000 in oracle virtual box I want to obtain the registry data of it, while using the regdump.exe but it says Application cannot be run in WIN32 mode. Is there any solution to make it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you extract the desired registry files and view them with external tools like [Nirsoft OfflineRegistryView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/offline_registry_view.html) or [Registry Viewer from AccessData](https://accessdata.com/product-download/registry-viewer-2-0-0) or similar tools?

Comment: Thank you this actually help, I also found another solution just like what you said I extracted it by using cmd command which is regedit then extract it to a notepad.